# How to use sybase in built function with prepared statement insert statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I want to use sybase inbuilt functions (isnull with string and char and convert(numeric(31,11),---) with prepared statement.

I was thinking in below way but could not achieve it.

First:

```
String query1 = "insert into dbase..tempTable values (nullif(?,'X'),nullif(?,'Y'),convert(numeric(31,11),?))";
    pst.setString(1,str);
    pst.setString(2,str2);
    pst.setString(3,a);
```

Second:

```
String query1 = "insert into dbase..tempTable values (?,?,?)";
pst.setString(1,"nullif(str1,'P")");
pst.setString(2,"nullif(str2,'PPP')");
pst.setDouble(3,------);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code :

```html
insert into dbase..tempTable(Column1, Column2, Column3)
select isnull(?,'X'),isnull(?,'Y'),cast(? as numeric(31,11))

pst.setString(1,str);
pst.setString(2,str2);
pst.setString(3,100);
```

Hope this helps :)